# Get the time that data was cached at from Cache() method of cacheout module in python

Tags: python, caching

I am using [cacheout](https://cacheout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle my caching because I had issues with cahcing a pandas df with cachetools. I read the docs, and I can't find a way to see when the cache was created or will expire. Is it possible to retrieve those data?

here is some example of code where I am caching some things.

```
import pandas as pd
from cacheout import Cache
cache=Cache(10,1000)

@cache.memoize()
def function1():
    df=pd.DataFrame({'one':range(5),'two':range(5,10)})  #just a little data, doesn't matter what
    print('iran')
    # return df.to_csv(index=False)
    return df

# @cached(cache)
@cache.memoize()
def function2(df):
    # df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df))
    var1=df['one']
    var2=df['two']
    print('iran2')
    return var1, var2

def function3():
    df=function1()
    var1,var2=function2(df)
    
    print('this is var1[0]: '+str(var1[0]))
    print('this is var2[0]: '+str(var2[0]))
    
function3()
```

Cacheout is here.
https://cacheout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: maybe it keeps it in some inner object and it doesn't have official function to give access to these value. You will have to check source code to see how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

As @furas mentioned, I was able to find something in the source code. There is a dictionary generating function that is a method of `cacheout.Cache()` called `expire_times()`. The time is given in epoc time, so here is an example to assign the expire time to a variable formatted in your local time.

```
from cacheout import Cache
import datetime as dt
cache = Cache(maxsize=10, ttl=60)
...
#Code to cache stuff
...


cache_expire=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(list(cache.expire_times().values())[0])
```

Note: In this case I just got the expire time of the first thing in the dictionary, but you can access the names of cached variables if that is important as well.

Also, this is in the docs, but I could only find it in the pdf version

https://cacheout.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/